# If $A \in \text{R-MOD}$, then $\text{Hom}_R(A,-)$ is left exact.

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation, modules, exact-sequence, functors

This is a lemma we went over in our class. I have a few questions about it.

If $0 \rightarrow B \stackrel{\varphi}{\rightarrow} B’ \stackrel{\psi}{\rightarrow} B’’ \rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence, we will need to prove that the following sequence is exact:
$$0 \rightarrow \text{Hom}(A,B) \stackrel{\varphi_\ast}{\rightarrow} \text{Hom}(A,B’) \stackrel{\psi_\ast}{\rightarrow} \text{Hom}(A,B’’)$$

where $\varphi_\ast = \text{Hom}(A,\varphi)$, and $\psi_\ast = \text{Hom}(A,\psi)$.

My questions are:

1. The proof in my class showed two things: that $\varphi_\ast$ is injective, and that $\text{ker } \psi_\ast = \text{im } \varphi_\ast$. Per the definition of exactness of sequence, don’t we also need to show that $\psi_\ast$ is surjective?
2. In the part that showed $\varphi_\ast$ is injective, a $f \in \text{Hom }(A,B)$ is chosen so that $\varphi_\ast(f) = 0$. Next we have $0 = \varphi_\ast(f) = \varphi f$. While I understand $\varphi_\ast(f)$ is in $\text{Hom}(A,B’)$, why do we must have $\varphi_\ast(f) = \varphi f$?
3. Related question: the next lemma showed that $\text{Hom }(-,A)$ is a left exact contravariant functor. This time we assume $0 \rightarrow B \stackrel{\alpha}{\rightarrow} C \stackrel{\beta}{\rightarrow} D \rightarrow 0$ is exact. In the part where we look at $\text{Hom}(D,A) \stackrel{\beta_\ast}{\rightarrow} \text{Hom}(C,A) \stackrel{\alpha_\ast}{\rightarrow} \text{Hom}(B,A)$, $\text{im } \beta_\ast$ is said to be in $\text{ker } \alpha_\ast$ by functoriality. Can I get an elaboration of this statement?

Comment: 1. No. It would be the case if there was a $\rightarrow 0$ at the end of the sequence, but $\psi_*$ is not surjective (in general). 2. is the definition of $\varphi_*(f)$.

Comment: 2. Could you elaborate? I’m trying to stick to the definition of functors, as I’m new to this concept. If we have $A \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} B \stackrel{\varphi}{\rightarrow} B’$, then by definition we should have $\text{Hom}(A,A) \stackrel{f_\ast}{\rightarrow} \text{Hom}(A,B) \stackrel{\varphi_\ast}{\rightarrow} \text{Hom}(A,B’)$ such that $(\varphi f)_\ast = \varphi_\ast f_\ast$. Now I’m confused since we have the new term $f_\ast$. I’m not sure what it is and how it’s related to the argument in the proof.

Comment: Well, $\varphi_* : \mathrm{Hom}(A, B) \to \mathrm{Hom}(A, B')$ is the image of $\varphi$ under the Hom-functor, which by definition is the map that sends $f \in \mathrm{Hom}(A, B)$ to the map $\varphi_*(f) = \varphi \circ f \in \mathrm{Hom}(A, B')$.

Answer (score 1):

For your last question, if we have a linear map $f:D\longrightarrow A$, then $$\beta_*(f)=f\beta\quad\text{and}\quad \alpha_*\bigl(\beta_*(f)\bigr)=(f\beta)\alpha=f(\beta\alpha)=f\,0=0.$$